Angular - subscribe in for- loop -> how to dedect end
I use this code in order to create sticky notes:
update() {
this.tab3Service.updateStickyNote(this.stickyNoteUserConnection.stickyNote).subscribe(response => {
  const updatedStickyNote: StickyNote = response;
  for(let i = 0; i < this.stickyNoteUserConnections.length; i++) {
    this.stickyNoteUserConnections[i].stickyNote = updatedStickyNote;
    this.tab3Service.updateStickyNoteUserConnection(this.stickyNoteUserConnections[i]).subscribe(response => {
    }, error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }
  this.createdEditEvent.emit(); // this should be executed after the for loop finished and all is saved at backend
  }, error => {
   console.log(error);
 });
}

Is there a possible to emit an event after all is saved in backend?

First, it would be easier to work with a single Observable and map the calls with switchMap. Second, a for loop is not a good choice to perform the requests as it doesn't wait for the Observable to complete. Instead, you can use forkJoin to trigger multiple request at once. Updated code:
update() {
  this.tab3Service.updateStickyNote(this.stickyNoteUserConnection.stickyNote)
    .pipe(
      switchMap(response => {
        const updatedStickyNote: StickyNote = response;
        this.stickyNoteUserConnections.forEach(connection =>
          connection.stickyNote = updatedStickyNote);
        return forkJoin(
          this.stickyNoteUserConnections.map(connection =>
            this.tab3Service.updateStickyNoteUserConnection(connection))
        );
      })
    )
    .subscribe({
      next: () => this.createdEditEvent.emit(),
      error: error => console.log(error),
    });
}

Additionally, I replaced the for loop with forEach, it's much shorter. Thanks @jaheraho for the suggestion.

Additionally the for loop could be done way shorter: this.stickCons.forEach(x => x.stickyNote = updatesStickyNote)
